# How to create a nested dictionary from a datastore model?

Tags: google-app-engine, dictionary, python, datastore

I am working on this problem a couple of days, my idea is from this model:

```
class oceni(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()
    weight = db.FloatProperty()
    item = db.StringProperty()
```

..to create a dictionary in this format:

```
collection = dict()
collection = {
    'user1':{'item1':weight1,'item2':weight2..},
    'user2':{'item3':weight3,'item4':weight4..},
..}
```

..and as far as I reached is this:

```
kontenier = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM oceni')

        kolekcija = dict()
        tmp = dict()
        lista = []
        for it in kontenier:
            lista.append(it.user)
        set = []
        for e in lista:
            if e not in set:
                set.append(e)
        for i in set:
            kontenier = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM oceni WHERE user=:1',i)
            for it in kontenier:
                tmp[it.item]=it.weight
            kolekcija[i]=tmp
```

..but this creates a dictionary where all the users have the same dictionary with items and their weight. I know this isn't the most pythonic way, but I'm new to this so I will be eager to learn something more about this problem.

Comment: It would be a good idea to not use type names (even in your own language) for variable names. It's better to use names that belong to the problem/solution domain.

Comment: @Apalala this is written with names that belong to my problem domain, but I renamed some of them, so the code would be more understandable for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used your variable names your notation in this snippet.

```
kontenier = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM oceni')
kolekcija = {}
for it in kontenier:
    if it.user not in kolekcija:
        kolekcija[it.user] = {}
    kolekcija[it.user][it.item] = it.weight
```

Comment: My idea was to complex, I still don't get it why it's not working..
But your code is clear, simple & functional, thanks!